# Difference between "in" and "to"?

Tags: grammar

> the Ambassador of X **to** the UN.
>
> the Ambassador of X **in** the UN.

Why is using *to* not *in*? What is to's *part of speech*?

Could I use `a user to Twitter` in English?

Comment: There seems to be a parallel here between ambassadors **to** a country and “ambassadors *to* the UN”. Even though the United Nations could be said to exist everywhere (in every member country) in fact we think of the places like New York where the various arms of it’s administration are based and it is here that the ambassadors travel *to* in order to take up their posts. Have a look at the dictionary definition of *to* and you will see it is a preposition.

Comment: Yes, “a user to Twitter” is possible, but unlikely. For example, *“That employee is confusing our clients. He sent **a user to Twitter** when really we should have sent them to our own website for that information.”*